# Parsing large text file with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that contains 100k+ lines here is a snippet:

```
:name ()
            :services_adtr (
                : (ReferenceObject
                    :Name (Any)
                    :Table (globals)
                    :Uid (97AEB369-9AEA-11D5-BD16-0090272CCNVF)
:src (
                :AdminInfo (
                    :chkpf_uid (ED8E5AB3-C793-42B0-AB9F-FFEFABDE4BxxA)
                    :ClassName (translate_hide)
                )
                : (ReferenceObject
                    :Name (h-10.140.20.20)
                    :Table (network_objects)
                    :Uid (37C4D635-C2F8-1644-9B2C-A09CD477777)
                )
                :adtr_method (adtr_method_hide)
```

for every section that starts with ":src", I need to extract everything in the parenthesis after ":Name" so in this case, how could I write a regex that gives me the "h-10.140.20.20? Here are the regexs I've tried so far, both return an empty list. Please note, that there are other sections in this document that start with "src_" "src-" - I need help with those sections that start with "src "..Thanks

```
import re

with open("INT-NAT.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()
source = re.findall(r'src\s+.*:Name\s+[\(](.*)', text) and
source = re.findall(r'src\s+.*\s+[\:].*\s+[\(].*[\)]\s+[\:].*\s+[\(].*[\)]\s+[\)\\s+[\:]\s+[\(].*\s+[\:]Name\s+[\(](.*)', text)

print(source)
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far, and what it produces?

Comment: check this https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip

Comment: here is another portion I'm have trouble with -- :src (
    :AdminInfo (
     :chkpf_uid (A6F28765-D095-4E52-8868-CA3746A9A1B2)
     :ClassName (rule_source)
    )
    :compound ()
    :op ()
    : (ReferenceObject
     :Name (Any)
     :Table (globals)
     :Uid (97AEB369-9AEA-2222-BD16-0090272CC6647) - In this case I would need to extract "(ANY)" nothing is working so far - I've tried this code import re
  
with open("INT-1dc-NAT.txt", "r") as f:
 text = f.read()

source = re.findall(r':src\s+.*\:Name\s[\(](.*)', text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will work as long as all of the lines are similar to the one you provided:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r':src_adtr_translate.*ReferenceObject\W+:Name \(([^\)]*)\)')
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        results = p.findall(line)
        print(results[-1])
```

The output for this code with a file containing the line you provided is:

```
h-10.140.20.20
```

As long as the `:Name` value you are looking for appears last, this should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, however, I could not get your code to work. I kept getting "list index out of range". I did however get it to work with this code source_adtr = re.findall(r':src_adtr_translated.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+:Name\s+[\(](.*)', text) print(source_adtr)....I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do it (new to python)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just trivially scan the file line by line, stripped each line, then checked that it starts with `:Name`, and cut off the things in the parens.

The above can be almost literally translated to Python; try doing that.